# Are there any guidelines for usability testing a Metro app?

Tags: usability-testing, metro, windows-8, new-experience

How do I conduct usability test on a new Win-8 Metro application when the expected users don't have any experience on that platform?

I'm going to test on PC and not on tablet.

Comment: You need to be more specific,is this a metro app for mobiles or for the windows 8 platform ?

Comment: Either in a lab, so subjects have direct access to your new platform or via remote desktop sharing.

Comment: It's a windows metro application for PC and tablets. Testing on PC in a lab.

Comment: What kind of testing do you want to conduct?

Comment: I'm going to invite the participant to our office, it's not going to be a remote test.

Answer (score 3):

Found it!

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700399

Also for new users on Win8 platform I will ask to commit 1-2 tasks to get used to the Metro style apps such as - "Download a new application from store and update other applications if available..." - The participants should get to know the charms menu, and the app-bar functions before testing the actual app.

Answer (score 0):

1) Check if your Metro UI app conforms to design guidelines ,here are some guidelines to get you started

[Windows Mobile Design guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb158602.aspx)

[Windows touch design guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc872774.aspx)

[Windows User experience guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511440.aspx)

2) Check for [Accessibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh452726.aspx)

3) This link [Seven Guidelines For Designing High-Performance Mobile User Experiences](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/07/18/seven-guidelines-for-designing-high-performance-mobile-user-experiences/) is generic with regards to app design and what are the attributes you need to look for but from an UX perspective they are applicable across all platforms

Comment: She's asking about testing, not designing.

Comment: The second item is a direct link to "Testing your app for accessibility" +1

Comment: Accessibility and usability are 2 very different things.

Comment: It sure is @dnbrv, but the question is unclear if its "usability" or "accessibility" testing.

Comment: It's a usability testing.

Comment: Though I agree accessibility and usability are two separate things, accessibility is a part of usability especially when you are looking at a diverse audience

Answer (score 0):

This is hard as **at present** your subject are unlikely to be used to using metro apps, so if you are not careful the results will lead to a app that in a years’ time will not be good for someone that is then used to metro apps.

One solution is to use Windows Phone 7 users for your testing.